# Is Python runtime needed to use Tensorflow.js Node?

Tags: tensorflow.js

As mentioned in the node version installation instructions, is Python runtime needed to use Tensorflow.js Node? I can install whatever is required but not sure if our production servers have it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what you want to do.

If you already have a tensorflow model written in python that you would like to deploy for inference in nodejs,

- you can use the tensorflow.js converter. In this case you will need a python runtime
- since the version 1.3 of tfjs-node, it is possible to load directly the savedModel in js (only possible in nodejs) using [loadSavedModel](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_node/1.5.1/#node.loadSavedModel).

But If you want to write your complete pipeline in js, you don't need to have python installed.

Comment: Yes I want to use Python model for inference without conversion using their loadSavedModel node.js function

Comment: You can't use python model without conversion. The python model needs to be converted in a model understandable by the js api. And for that you will need the tfjs converter

Comment: Actually this is a new feature since 1.3.2 in tfjs-node https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!starred/tfjs/Xtf6s1Bpkr0

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot that you can directly load the savedModel. I will update the answer